# Read NUL-terminated String from ByteBuffer

Tags: java, nio, bytebuffer, text-decoding

How can I read NUL-terminated UTF-8 string from Java `ByteBuffer` starting at `ByteBuffer#position()`?

```java
ByteBuffer b = /* 61 62 63 64 00 31 32 34 00 (hex) */;
String s0 = /* read first string */;
String s1 = /* read second string */;

// `s0` will now contain “ABCD” and `s1` will contain “124”.
```

I have already tried using `Charsets.UTF_8.decode(b)` but it seems this function is ignoring current `ByteBuffer` postision and reads until the end of the buffer.

Is there more idiomatic way to read such string from byte buffer than seeking for byte containing 0 and the limiting the buffer to it (or copying the part with string into separate buffer)?

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  Post your own efforts and tell us what problems you're having.

Comment: For lower level functionality I'd look into `CharsetDecoder`...

Comment: Err, read characters untlil you get the NUL? Unclear what the problem is here.

Comment: Have you tried reading byte by byte in a loop and populating a `byte[]` and then instantiate a `new String( bytes[], StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );`?

Comment: @Jim, Yes but I think it is unnecessarily complicated since it is possible (at least in theory) to use the original buffer.

Comment: @jiwopene: I don't really get your point. You do have multiple strings to decode right? So at some point the code needs to loop

Comment: I have input containing integers (in binary format), individual characters, and NUL-terminated strings in known order. I want to deserialize the data.

Answer (score 6):

Idiomatic meaning "one liner" not that I know of (unsurprising since NUL-terminated strings are not part of the Java spec).

The first thing I came up with is using `b.slice().limit(x)` to create a lightweight view onto the desired bytes only (better than copying them anywhere as you might be able to work directly with the buffer)

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x00, 0x31, 0x32, 0x34, 0x00 });
int i;
while (b.hasRemaining()) {
  ByteBuffer nextString = b.slice(); // View on b with same start position
  for (i = 0; b.hasRemaining() && b.get() != 0x00; i++) {
    // Count to next NUL
  }
  nextString.limit(i); // view now stops before NUL
  CharBuffer s = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(nextString);
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java the char `\u0000`, the UTF-8 byte 0, the Unicode code point U+0 is a normal char. So read all (maybe into an overlarge byte array), and do

```
String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

String[] s0s1 = s.split("\u0000");
String s0 = s0s1[0];
String s1 = s0s1[1];
```

If you do not have fixed positions and must sequentially read every byte the code is ugly. One of the C founders indeed called the nul terminated string a historic mistake.

The reverse, to not produce a UTF-8 byte 0 for a java String, normally for further processing as C/C++ nul terminated strings, there exists writing a modified UTF-8, also encoding the 0 byte.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by **replace** and **split** functions. Convert your hex bytes to String and find 0 by a custom character. Then split your string with that custom character.

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Administrator on 8/25/2020.
 */
public class Jtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //ByteBuffer b = /* 61 62 63 64 00 31 32 34 00 (hex) */;
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);

        b.put((byte)0x61);
        b.put((byte)0x62);
        b.put((byte)0x63);
        b.put((byte)0x64);
        b.put((byte)0x00);
        b.put((byte)0x31);
        b.put((byte)0x32);
        b.put((byte)0x34);
        b.put((byte)0x00);
        b.rewind();

        String s0;
        String s1;

        // print the ByteBuffer
        System.out.println("Original ByteBuffer:  "
                + Arrays.toString(b.array()));

        // `s0` will now contain “ABCD” and `s1` will contain “124”.
        String s = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(b).toString();
        String ss = s.replace((char)0,';');
        String[] words = ss.split(";");
        for(int i=0; i < words.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(" Word " + i + " = " +words[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

I believe you can do it more efficiently with removing replace.